# How to convert Set to string with space?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, set

I want to convert JavaScript `Set` to `string` with space.

For example, if I have a set like:

```
var foo = new Set();
foo.add('hello');
foo.add('world');
foo.add('JavaScript');
```

And I'd like to print the string from the set: `hello world JavaScript` (space between each element).

I tried below codes but they are not working:

```
foo.toString(); // Not working
String(foo); // Not working
```

Is there **simplest and easiest way** to convert from **Set** to **string**?

Comment: `[...foo].join(' ')`

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(foo).join(' ')
```

or the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
[...foo].join(' ')
```

Comment: Array.from is not supported by internet Explorer, if someone has to maintain the compatibility of its script, any other suggestion?

Comment: `Array.from` is significantly faster in large sets, though.

Comment: Use a polyfill @SimonaAdriani

Comment: [Speed comparisons](https://jsbench.me/o1ld6am6ze/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the set and build an array of the elements and return the desired string by joining the array.

```
var foo = new Set();
foo.add('hello');
foo.add('world');
foo.add('JavaScript');
let strArray = [];

for(str of foo){
  strArray.push(str);
}

console.log(strArray.join(" "));
```