# Intersection of two sets displays [object set]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, set

How do I get to display the elements that make up the intersection of two sets without it displaying `[object set]` ?

```js
const setA = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const setB = new Set([3, 4, 5, 6]);

function intersection(setA, setB) {
  const result = new Set();
  for (const elem of setA) {
    if (setB.has(elem)) { 
      result.add(elem);
    } 
  }
  return result; 
}

console.log(intersection(setA, setB));
```

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243139/how-to-convert-set-to-string-with-space

Comment: There are several different ways. MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) e.g.:

```js
const setA = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const setB = new Set([3, 4, 5, 6]);

function intersection(setA, setB) {
  const result = new Set();
  for (const elem of setA) {
    if (setB.has(elem)) { 
      result.add(elem);
    } 
  }
  return result; 
}

const matches = Array.from(intersection(setA, setB));
console.log(matches);
```